# hiding a form from the page complete still effects the search on submit

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am trying to load the same form but slightly rearranged html based on screen size.

I know this can be achieved with css but this is not what I am after as I have specific pages where I don't want the form to load so I am using php to check what page I am on and show/hide the form depending on the page.

Both search.php and search_mobile.php are using the same forms and everything is the same except minor html rearranging.

On submission, even though the mobile form is hidden, it still affect the search results. Is there any way to completely hide it? I tried visibility:hidden but that's just visually hidding it and display:none doesn't seem to work either..

```
<form method="get" action="">   

    <?php include 'search.php'; ?> 

    <div id="mobile" style="display:none;">
        <?php include 'search_mobile.php'; ?>
    </div>

    ...more code
</form>
```

Comment: When do you show the mobile version instead of the other one?

Comment: Why would having specific pages where you want the form to be hidden prevent you from solving this via CSS?

Comment: I am not sure how to use css to hide the element in a specific page. How can I tell css that when the page is index.php, hide the div?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the condition for loading the mobile or the default. When you have this condition, you won't have to hide it, you just don't include it on the page... The result html won't even contain the code.

```
<form method="get" action="">   

    <?php 
        if( /* CONDITION FOR SHOWING MOBILE OR DEFAULT */ )
            include 'search.php'; 
        else
            include 'search_mobile.php';
    ?> 
    ...more code
</form>
```

Comment: what will go in the condition is my question!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure exactly what is happening or what you are trying to achieve but I would check that each form tag, they needs to have their own name attribute to work exclusively on a page.

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="">   

    <?php include 'search.php'; ?> 

    ...more code
</form>


<form name="form2" method="get" action="">   

    <div id="mobile" style="display:none;">
        <?php include 'search_mobile.php'; ?>
    </div>

    ...more code
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any input element in the form is submitted, regardless it it's visible or not. You can solve it by disabling the elements before submit.

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).find(':input').not(':visible').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

No need to change the HTML or PHP.